# HTML embedded Vimeo player fails in Cordova CLI 5.4.1 and 6.2.0

Tags: ios, cordova, vimeo, intel-xdk, vimeo-ios

I'm using the Intel XDK to build my Cordova app. I have an HTML/Javascript app that plays embedded Vimeo videos fine in web browsers.

When I build with Cordova CLI 5.1.1 things work fine as well for the iOS and Android apps.

When I build using Cordova CLI 5.4.1 or Cordova CLI 6.2.0 the Android app continues to play back Vimeo videos without issue, however for the iOS build the playback does not happen. The video area is still taking up the same amount of space, but displays a plain transparent/empty area with nothing visible in front of the background.

I started a topic here on the Vimeo forums without response.
https://vimeo.com/forums/help/topic:283713

In another thread, they responded briefly saying Vimeo does not support inline playback on mobile.

Any ideas on what might be a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this issue was caused by the Whitelist changes to either the Intel XDK, or new versions of Cordova.

In the Intel XDK, under Projects -> Build Settings -> Whitelist > Navigation () I added *.vimeo.com

This caused the XDK file to update, in the following way:

```
"project": {
  "buildConfigurations": {
    "iOS": {
      "appAccess_": {
        "mode": "whitelist",
        "network": [
          "*"
        ],
        "intents": [],
        "navigation": [
          "*.vimeo.com"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After this change, embedded Vimeo videos played fine in iOS app builds using Cordova 6.2.0

Note, the Network Request () entry under Whitelist was set to '*', not sure if that was relevant.